# How to wait for query in graphQL to finish before proceeding?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, graphql

I have a code below where in I want to finish `doSomethingFirst()` before proceeding with the rest of the code:

```
async doSomething() {
    const response = await doSomethingFirst(); // get the response from this first

    if(response) {
        // rest of the code
    }

}

async doSomethingFirst {
    const response = await client
        .query({
            query,
            fetchPolicy: "network-only",
            variables: {
                someVariable: value
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            // error
        });
    return await response;    
}
```

However, the response in `doSomething()` comes back as `undefined`. What's wrong with this structure?

Comment: Where is all of this present? inside a class?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, normally works for me, if not maybe the problem is elsewhere an it's not returning and actual data?

```
async doSomethingFirst {
const response = await client
    .query({
        query,
        fetchPolicy: "network-only",
        variables: {
            someVariable: value
        }
    })
    .then(response => { return response.json();})
    .then(responseData => {console.log(responseData); return responseData;})
    .catch(err => {
        // error
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should return the response. Anyway, you can just do something like this:

```
doSomethingFirst() {
  return client
    .query({
      query,
      fetchPolicy: "network-only",
      variables: {
        someVariable: value
      }
    })
}

async doSomething() {
  try {
    const response = await doSomethingFirst();
    if (response) {
      // rest of the code
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

A few things you might want to know:

1. Inside `doSomethingFirst` you are using `await` and also chaining `.then` you don't have to do that because they're the same.
2. I made `doSomethingFirst` a non-async function because since `doSomething` is an async function you can just return the promise from `doSomethingFirst` and await the response inside `doSomething` also error handling can be done with the try-catch blocks as I did.